# Consuming a service operation from .net client give me an error

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

If I consume my service operation from the browser, it works perfectly.

If I consume my service operation from .net client, it gives me an error

"The type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyEntity]' has no settable properties."

Any idea? Thanks.

Client code:

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> CallMyOperation(string param1 = "", string param2 = "") {
        DataServiceQuery<IQueryable<MyEntity>> q =
            CreateQuery<IQueryable<MyEntity>>("MyOperation")
                .AddQueryOption("param1", "'" + param1 + "'")
                .AddQueryOption("param2", "'" + param2 + "'");
        return
            Execute<IQueryable<MyEntity>>(
                new Uri(q.RequestUri.ToString().Replace("MyOperation()", "MyOperation"))).
                FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Wcf Service code:

```
        [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<MyEntity> MyOperation(string param1 = "", string param2 = "") {
     ...
    }

    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) {
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion =
            DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntity", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyOperation", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the service operation method call from the .net client and the service operation header (to see return values and parameters)? Without those details I can tell you more than to pay attention to Service Operation Requirements from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx

Comment: @CoralDoe I put the code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you sure that param1 and param2 are valid query string options to add?

Comment: @CoralDoe The names are just example. In any case call from browser works perfectly so I think there is no problem about parameter format.

Comment: Have you tried just `return Execute<MyEntity>(...).AsQueryable()`? I'm not sure whether `Execute<IQueryable<MyEntity>>` will cause an error or not, but it doesn't look right to me. I can try on my end if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `Execute<T>` should just have the generic type you want materialized, not an `IQueryable<T>`. When the materialization process runs, it tries to set properties on the object from the entities it received in the `WebResponse`. Since `IQueryable<T>` doesn't have the properties you're getting back on the wire, materialization fails.

If you still want an `IQueryable`, you can call `Execute<MyEntity>(...).AsQueryable()`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Although I dont understand this - when the return type on the Odata Action method is Iquerable<T> shouldnt the execute action match the return type. Am I missing something?